# IE 10 - div being pushed down despite parent position:relative

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, position, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a browser compatibility issue with IE 10. To compensate for negative top margins that were pushing this div down in earlier versions of ie, I positioned the parent div relative but this fix doesn't seem to work in ie10. Here's my code:

```
<div class="hidden-panel">
<div class="gradient-wrap">
    <div class="calls">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="/"><img src="bully-call1.png"></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="/"><img src="bully-call2.png"></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="/"><img src="bully-call3.png"></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="blue-window">
      <img src="take-pledge.png">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.gradient-wrap{
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background: url(gradientbg.png) repeat-x;
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: relative;
}

.calls{
  width: 60%;
  }

.hidden-panel{
    background-image: url(hidden-panel.png);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

.blue-window{
  background-color: $theme_color_6;
  padding: 45px 180px 45px 0px;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 100px auto 30px;
  }
```

Here's the site: http://www.thebullyproject.com/home2

Comment: your link doesn't work :-)

Comment: Thanks Tanner! Total rookie mistake.

Comment: also the banner of your site not position properly in **ff 19.0.2**

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% sure why right now, but it looks like the content is being pushed down in IE10 as there isn't enough room for it with the left padding you also have.

If you change the `padding-left` to `22px` on `.gradient-wrap` it will work as expected (with a little less padding).